# Appending data sets to an OpenPyxl Chart using a For-Loop

Tags: python, openpyxl

[image]

In Python, I have the ability to add series data to my chart object to plot as a line graph.

I'm using the following lines:

```
overall_stats_sheet2            = current_book.worksheets[0] 
overall_chart_sheet             = current_book.worksheets[1]
chart_object                    = charts.LineChart()
for x in top_down_reference_points[0]:
    chart_object.append(charts.Series(charts.Reference(overall_stats_sheet, (x,1),  (x, overall_stats_sheet2.get_highest_column()+1)), title = 'Erasure Decodes'))
chart_object.drawing.top        = 0
chart_object.drawing.left       = 400
chart_object.drawing.width      = 650
chart_object.drawing.height     = 400

overall_chart_sheet.add_chart(chart_object)
```

top_down_reference_points[0] contains all of the row numbers that erasure decode exists on. In the example picture, the numbers are row 19 and row 39.

My for loop code currently iterates through those and appends them to the graph, but it creates a new legend label and line for each erasure-decode set. I want to combine all that data from the sheet and graph one line associated with all the erasure decode data. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your code which cells you want in your chart and how. It may be as simple as creating a single series that refers to multiple cells. At the moment you're creating multiple series which is why you're seeing multiple items in the legend.

BTW. I strongly recommend you start using the 2.3 beta of openpyxl which has much better chart support.

Comment: Have you added openpyxl documentation anywhere for 2.3 b1? How can I create a series to refer to multiple cells? That might better answer my question

Comment: Yes. It turns out that a second axis actually means adding a second chart… the semantics are a bit weird as a result but it seems to work okay.

Comment: Great, I needed that feature for this project. Is it possible for you to rewrite your answer to explain how I can add multiple cell locations to one series?

Comment: Don't the examples in the current docs have something close? I suspect you're referring to the data dump from your other question? If so, Pandas is your friend.

Comment: I've read through a bunch of pages you have written, but failing to see how I can append reference points to the same series.